# PhantomJS GhostDriver XPath not working

Tags: java, phantomjs, ghostdriver

I am trying to run a simple GoogleSuggest example using PhantomJS and GhostDriver for Java from eclipse IDE, however it does not find any elements by Xpath , if I use another driver like Firefox I am able to find elements using the same Xpath expression . Can someone please let me know what I am doing wrong here ? Is Xpath supported in GhostDriver, am I missing anything in my maven dependecies ?

The following line always returns empty list.

```
List<WebElement> allSuggestions = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//td[@class='gssb_a gbqfsf']"));`
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated ! Thanks.

My Simple Class

```
import java.util.List;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.phantomjs.PhantomJSDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.phantomjs.PhantomJSDriverService;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;

    public class GoogleSuggest {
        public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
            // The Firefox driver supports javascript 
            //WebDriver driver = new PhantomJSDriver();

            DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.phantomjs();
            capabilities.setCapability(PhantomJSDriverService.PHANTOMJS_EXECUTABLE_PATH_PROPERTY,
                    "/usr/local/bin/phantomjs");                    
            PhantomJSDriver driver = new PhantomJSDriver(capabilities);

            // Go to the Google Suggest home page
            driver.get("http://www.google.com/webhp?complete=1&hl=en");

            // Enter the query string "Cheese"
            WebElement query = driver.findElement(By.name("q"));
            query.sendKeys("Cheese");

            // Sleep until the div we want is visible or 5 seconds is over
            long end = System.currentTimeMillis() + 5000;
            while (System.currentTimeMillis() < end) {
                WebElement resultsDiv = driver.findElement(By.className("gssb_e"));

                // If results have been returned, the results are displayed in a drop down.
                if (resultsDiv.isDisplayed()) {
                  break;
                }
            }

            // And now list the suggestions
            List<WebElement> allSuggestions = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//td[@class='gssb_a gbqfsf']"));

            for (WebElement suggestion : allSuggestions) {
                System.out.println(suggestion.getText());
            }
         }
    }
```

Eclipse Console Output :

```
    Jan 01, 2014 2:37:14 PM org.openqa.selenium.phantomjs.PhantomJSDriverService <init>
INFO: executable: /usr/local/bin/phantomjs
Jan 01, 2014 2:37:14 PM org.openqa.selenium.phantomjs.PhantomJSDriverService <init>
INFO: port: 23886
Jan 01, 2014 2:37:14 PM org.openqa.selenium.phantomjs.PhantomJSDriverService <init>
INFO: arguments: [--webdriver=23886, --webdriver-logfile=/home/general/workspace/TestSample/phantomjsdriver.log]
Jan 01, 2014 2:37:14 PM org.openqa.selenium.phantomjs.PhantomJSDriverService <init>
INFO: environment: {}
PhantomJS is launching GhostDriver...
[INFO  - 2014-01-01T19:37:14.707Z] GhostDriver - Main - running on port 23886
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.apache.http.impl.conn.tsccm.ThreadSafeClientConnManager).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
[INFO  - 2014-01-01T19:37:15.345Z] Session [1e2756e0-731c-11e3-b767-e95df6be38fb] - _decorateNewWindow - page.settings: {"XSSAuditingEnabled":false,"javascriptCanCloseWindows":true,"javascriptCanOpenWindows":true,"javascriptEnabled":true,"loadImages":true,"localToRemoteUrlAccessEnabled":false,"userAgent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Unknown; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/534.34 (KHTML, like Gecko) PhantomJS/1.9.2 Safari/534.34","webSecurityEnabled":true}
[INFO  - 2014-01-01T19:37:15.345Z] Session [1e2756e0-731c-11e3-b767-e95df6be38fb] - page.customHeaders:  - {}
[INFO  - 2014-01-01T19:37:15.345Z] Session [1e2756e0-731c-11e3-b767-e95df6be38fb] - CONSTRUCTOR - Desired Capabilities: {"platform":"ANY","browserName":"phantomjs","phantomjs.binary.path":"/usr/local/bin/phantomjs","version":""}
[INFO  - 2014-01-01T19:37:15.345Z] Session [1e2756e0-731c-11e3-b767-e95df6be38fb] - CONSTRUCTOR - Negotiated Capabilities: {"browserName":"phantomjs","version":"1.9.2","driverName":"ghostdriver","driverVersion":"1.0.4","platform":"linux-unknown-64bit","javascriptEnabled":true,"takesScreenshot":true,"handlesAlerts":false,"databaseEnabled":false,"locationContextEnabled":false,"applicationCacheEnabled":false,"browserConnectionEnabled":false,"cssSelectorsEnabled":true,"webStorageEnabled":false,"rotatable":false,"acceptSslCerts":false,"nativeEvents":true,"proxy":{"proxyType":"direct"}}
[INFO  - 2014-01-01T19:37:15.346Z] SessionManagerReqHand - _postNewSessionCommand - New Session Created: 1e2756e0-731c-11e3-b767-e95df6be38fb
[INFO  - 2014-01-01T19:42:14.705Z] SessionManagerReqHand - _cleanupWindowlessSessions - Asynchronous Sessions clean-up phase starting NOW
[INFO  - 2014-01-01T19:47:14.754Z] SessionManagerReqHand - _cleanupWindowlessSessions - Asynchronous Sessions clean-up phase starting NOW
```

My Maven Entries:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.github.detro.ghostdriver</groupId>
    <artifactId>phantomjsdriver</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.4</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
    <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
    <version>2.39.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: And are there definitely any elements which match that XPath in the document you get when making the request with that driver?  The server may be doing some user agent sniffing and sending different content from that which you got through Firefox.

Comment: ok the server could possibly be rendering different content for different browsers, because when I use the same exact code and replace the PhantomDriver with Firefox every thinks works as expected. How could I verify this though ?

Answer (score 0):

This might work. Ignore the previous tool - It is more inhouse product built by our team and we are in process for making it open source.

Till then you can explore: http://yslow.org/phantomjs/